# Google authentication with load balancer in c#

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, traefik

I have implemented a Load Balancer with Traefik in this way:

```
http:
  routers:
    mydomain-web-http:
      service: mydomain-web
      rule: "Host(`mydomain.com`,`www.mydomain.com`)"
      entryPoints:
        - http
      middlewares:
        - https-redirect
    mydomain-web-https:
      service: mydomain-web
      rule: "Host(`mydomain.com`,`www.mydomain.com`)"
      entryPoints:
        - https
      tls:
        certResolver: letsEncrypt

  services:
    mydomain-web:
      loadBalancer:
        sticky:
          cookie:
            name: mydomain_sticky
            secure: true
            httpOnly: true
        passHostHeader: false
        servers:
          - url: https://www2.mydomain.com
          - url: https://www1.mydomain.com
```

Now I configure a webapp client OAuth 2.0. for login with google in this way:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var googleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions
                    {
                        ClientId = "xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
                        ClientSecret = "-sn_xxx",
                     
                        Provider = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationProvider()
                        {
                            OnAuthenticated = async context =>
                            {
                                context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("GoogleAccessToken", context.AccessToken));
                            }
                        }
                    };
        
                    app.UseGoogleAuthentication(googleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions);
        
        
    }
```

Before the configuration with Load balancer this code work fine but now I receive this error:

Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch
The redirect URI in the request, https://www2.mydomain.com/signin-google, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client...

i need to authorize google login for my "main" domain ([www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com))... I try to achieves this in this way:

> ```
>         app.Use((ctx, next) =>
>         {
>             ctx.Request.Host = new HostString("www.mydomain.com");
>             return next();
>         });
> ```

with no luck...

Answer (score 1):

after to much pain, i solved by setting the schema in this way:

> ```
>    app.Use((ctx, next) =>
>         {
>             ctx.Request.Scheme = "https";
>             ctx.Request.Host = new HostString("www.mydomain.com");
>             return next();
>         });
> ```